# how to disable the action of the form via jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

is it possible to disable the submission of the form given a certain condition?
here's my sample code

```
        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@gmail.com" />
        <?php
          $i = 1;
          foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $qty):
          $product = $myCart->getProduct($id);

        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['ProductName']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['ProductID']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['ProductOverridePrice']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>">
      <?php
        $i++;
        endforeach;
      ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="<?php echo $shipping; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://testsite/thankyou.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://testsite/">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://testsite/paypal.php">
        <input type="image" src="images/shopping-cart/check-out-btn.png" name="pay now" value="pay" />
        </form>
```

let's say I have a condition where the form should "not" be submitted if
$_SESSION['cart'] is empty , how to do that ?

I tried one of the answers at the bottom..I placed the code at the bottom of the file like this

```
<?php
if(!is_array($_SESSION['cart']) && empty($_SESSION['cart'])):
?>
<script>
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

didn't work..when i push the checkout button it still goes to the paypal sandbox page

Comment: return false to stop the action

Comment: In this file, why don't you test `$_SESSION['cart']` before print the form ?

Comment: On server-side if $_SESSION['cart'] is empty you can disable the submit button; on client-side make a function to intercept the submission and check the user's cart first (this state should be passed to the client-site beforehand) then act accordingly.

Comment: because, the only visible to the front-end is the input type image thing..it's the checkout button ..the rest of the form is hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the HTML output dependent on the $_SESSION['cart'] status:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" <?php if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){echo "onsubmit=\"return false;\""} ?>>...
```

If you specifically want to involve jquery, just give the form an id and to the same as above, but with js:

```
<?php 
if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
   echo "
     $('#form_id').submit(function() {
        return false;
     });
   "
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`onsubmit="return false"` or `$('form').submit(function(){return false;});`

Comment: I was going to up-vote this - but then I realized that it does not answer the "given a certain condition?" piece so it is not actually a good answer given the actual question details. so I will have to flag

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

... is more correct than `return false;`. At least, as long as it's stopping the submission of the form that we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via javascript,pass value of $_SESSION['cart'] to java script function and call this on form submit,like this :

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onSubmit="return stop_form_submit("<?php  echo $_SESSION['cart']; ?>");">
```

and then in javascript,

```
function stop_form_submit(cart_val) {
    if(!cart_val) { 
       return false;
    }

}
```